# Remove tag if attribute exists

Tags: python-2.7, lxml, elementtree

I have an xml file that looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MD_Metadata xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <identificationInfo>
      <MD_DataIdentification>
         <descriptiveKeywords>
            <MD_Keywords>
               <keyword>
                  <gco:CharacterString>Keyword1</gco:CharacterString>
               </keyword>
            </MD_Keywords>
         </descriptiveKeywords>
         <descriptiveKeywords>
            <MD_Keywords>
               <keyword>
                  <gco:CharacterString />
               </keyword>
               <thesaurusName uuidref="723f6998-058e-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66" />
            </MD_Keywords>
         </descriptiveKeywords>
      </MD_DataIdentification>
   </identificationInfo>
</MD_Metadata>
```

What i would like to do is if the xml contains the **uuidref** attribute, i would like to remove the whole second  tag, so my output is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MD_Metadata xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <identificationInfo>
      <MD_DataIdentification>
         <descriptiveKeywords>
            <MD_Keywords>
               <keyword>
                  <gco:CharacterString>Keyword1</gco:CharacterString>
               </keyword>
            </MD_Keywords>
         </descriptiveKeywords>
      </MD_DataIdentification>
   </identificationInfo>
</MD_Metadata>
```

My issue is that when I try and xpath and find the uuidref attribute, nothing is returned.
When i look at the tags

```
for el in tree.iter():
 print el.tag
```

I get the following

```
{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}MD_Metadata
{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}identificationInfo
{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}MD_DataIdentification    
{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}descriptiveKeywords    
{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}MD_Keywords    
{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}keyword    
{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco}CharacterString    
{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}descriptiveKeywords    
{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}MD_Keywords    
{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}keyword    
{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco}CharacterString    
{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}thesaurusName
```

When i try and xpath with the mentioned tag

```
root.xpath("//{http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd}descriptiveKeywords")
```

i get the following
**XPathEvalError: Invalid expression**

So my questions are

1. how do i remove the whole descriptive tag, if it contains the uuidref attribute
2. Why are the urls being appended to the tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can do your filtering the following way:

```
from lxml import etree as et

# Read the XML file
parser = et.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
ns = {'gmd': 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd'}
tree = et.parse('Input.xml', parser)
root = tree.getroot()
# Processing loop
for it in root.findall('.//gmd:descriptiveKeywords', ns):
    if it.find('.//*[@uuidref]') is not None:
        it.getparent().remove(it)
# Print the result
print(et.tostring(root, method='xml', encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
```

Note that your XML is **namespaced**, so to refer to any element with
a namespace (even the default one) you must:

- define a namespace dictionary (I named it *ns*),
- specify element names with a proper namespace prefix,
- pass the above dictionary as the second parameter to (e.g.) *findall*.

The result is:

```
<MD_Metadata xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
    xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco">
  <identificationInfo>
    <MD_DataIdentification>
      <descriptiveKeywords>
        <MD_Keywords>
          <keyword>
            <gco:CharacterString>Keyword1</gco:CharacterString>
          </keyword>
        </MD_Keywords>
      </descriptiveKeywords>
    </MD_DataIdentification>
  </identificationInfo>
</MD_Metadata>
```

Caution: I wrote the above code using *Python* **3.8**. Not sure whether
it will work in version *2.7*. If not, maybe you should consider upgrading
your software.

Answer (score 0):

Another method, which has the same results in version 2.7 and 3+

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
xml = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MD_Metadata xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <identificationInfo>
      <MD_DataIdentification>
         <descriptiveKeywords>
            <MD_Keywords>
               <keyword>
                  <gco:CharacterString>Keyword1</gco:CharacterString>
               </keyword>
            </MD_Keywords>
         </descriptiveKeywords>
         <descriptiveKeywords>
            <MD_Keywords>
               <keyword>
                  <gco:CharacterString />
               </keyword>
               <thesaurusName uuidref="723f6998-058e-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66" />
            </MD_Keywords>
         </descriptiveKeywords>
      </MD_DataIdentification>
   </identificationInfo>
</MD_Metadata>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
els = doc.getElementsByReg(' uuidref="')
for el in els:
  el.getParent(tag='descriptiveKeywords').repleaceSelf('')
print (doc.html)
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MD_Metadata xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <identificationInfo>
      <MD_DataIdentification>
         <descriptiveKeywords>
            <MD_Keywords>
               <keyword>
                  <gco:CharacterString>Keyword1</gco:CharacterString>
               </keyword>
            </MD_Keywords>
         </descriptiveKeywords>
         
      </MD_DataIdentification>
   </identificationInfo>
</MD_Metadata>
```